How to implement automatic logout in Next.js with next-auth for "remember me" functionality?
I'm developing a Next.js (v14.1.3) application using next-auth (v4.24.7) for authentication. I'm trying to implement a "remember me" functionality with automatic logout. The desired behavior is:
1.- If a user logs in without checking "remember me", their session should automatically end when they open the app in a new tab.
2.- If "remember me" is checked, the session should persist across tabs and browser restarts.
Currently, I'm using sessionStorage for non-remembered sessions and localStorage for remembered ones. I've attempted to implement the logout using next-auth's signOut function within a useEffect hook, checking the sessionStorage value.
However, I'm encountering inconsistent behavior:
Sometimes the session closes in all tabs
Other times it only closes in one tab
Occasionally, it appears to close but then reactivates on page reload
In some cases, it creates an infinite loop between authenticated and unauthenticated states
I'm using Next.js middleware for route protection, which may be complicating the issue. I need a reliable way to implement this "remember me" functionality that works consistently across all scenarios.
I attempted to implement the automatic logout using a combination of sessionStorage, localStorage, and next-auth's signOut function within a useEffect hook. Here's what I tried:
const logoutUser = useCallback(async () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('rememberme');
  sessionStorage.removeItem('rememberme');
  await signOut({ redirect: false });
  router.replace('/login');
}, [router])

useEffect(() => {
  const rememberMeSession = sessionStorage.getItem('rememberme');
  if (rememberMeSession !== 'false') {
    logoutUser();
  }
}, [session?.user, user, logoutUser])

Expected behavior:
1.- When a user opens a new tab without "remember me" checked, the session should automatically end.
2.- The logout should be consistent across all tabs.
3.- Users with "remember me" checked should remain logged in across tabs and browser restarts.
Actual results:
1.- Inconsistent logout behavior: sometimes all tabs logout, other times only one tab logs out.
2.- Occasional "infinite loop" between authenticated and unauthenticated states.
3.- In some cases, the session appears to end but reactivates upon manual page reload.
4.- The logout doesn't always trigger when opening a new tab, contrary to the intended "remember me" functionality.
These inconsistencies make the current implementation unreliable and confusing for users.
